# Problem in displaying django formset errors

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using formset to get multiple user inputs where users can set the `Delete` form checkbox if needed. But there should be at least 1 form as provided in `min_num` argument to the formset. However, when the user check all forms to be deleted formset `is_valid()` method fails without showing any errors. It just show `[{}, {}]` when printed `formset.errors` attribute. (django v. 1.11.3)

```
if formset.is_valid():
    ...
else:
    print(formset.errors) # this prints [{}, {}]
    return self.render_to_response(context_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple forms so you cant print errors directly .Try displayijng the errors in template like this:

```
{% if formset.errors %}
{% for field in formset %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
 {% for error in formset.non_field_errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```